# How to express an angle of 90 degrees between two lines?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If I would extend two lines $l_1$ and $l_2$ they would intersect with an angle of 90 degrees. How should I write with math terms that there would be a 90 degree angle. I assume $l_1 \perp l_2$ is wrong if they do not intersect (when not extending them).

Is there a possibility to express a 90 degree angle between an extension of $l_1$ and $l_2$? How to express an extension of $l_1$?

Comment: $l_1$ is perpendicular to $l_2$ - which is what the symbol you use means - seems adequate to me.  Or "orthogonal to", perhaps, if you think "perpendicular" implies an intersection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally *lines* are thought to go on indefinitely (they don't have endpoints), so the $l_1$ and $l_2$ you are describing should really be called *line segments*. With that in mind you could say something like:

> Let $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ be the lines that contain the line segments $l_1$ and $l_2$ respectively. Note that $\ell_1 \perp \ell_2$.

Answer (score 1):

We can recognize by what changes occur in the equation of the line.The product of slopes is -1.

If the lines are in slope intercept form

$$ y= m  x + a   \,\rightarrow y= -x/m + const $$

If in full intercept form

$$ \frac{x}{a}+ \frac{y}{b} =1   \rightarrow \frac{x}{b} - \frac{y}{a} = const $$

If in polar form

$$ x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha = p \, \rightarrow -x \sin  \alpha + y \cos \alpha = q $$

etc.